# Why cant I write select clause in if statement?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to active something below in AmazonRedshift:

```
 IF  
(SELECT 
  count(*) 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE table_name = 'ABC'
  AND column_name = 'COLUMN'
  and table_schema ='SCHEMA'
) > 0 
THEN
  RAISE INFO 'table present';
ELSE
  RAISE INFO 'Table not present';
END IF;
```

I am getting error below:

> Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "IF"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `IF` is not part of SQL. You can run the SQL statement in the database (the `SELECT ...`). With that result you can execute an `IF` in the programming language you are using to query the database.

Comment: Redshift is **not** Postgres. Please do not add tags that are not relevant

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. I think it will work.

DECLARE @counter bigint=0;

SELECT  @counter = count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'ABC' AND column_name = 'COLUMN' and table_schema ='SCHEMA'

IF (@counter) > 0

BEGIN

print('Table exists');

END

ELSE

BEGIN

```
print('Table does not exists');
```

END